# Error TypeError: undefined is not an object with Global Variable

Tags: javascript, html, xml

EDIT: Other solutions don't make use of XML calling, despite reading other questions still don't understand how to fix the code here.

I'm new to JavaScript/HTML, right now I'm making a simple application that reads XML data and displays it, essentially I have data for a bunch of magazines (cover, release date, etc) on the left side of the app there is a list of each issue, I'm working with over 300, so doing it by hand would take too long, so I wrote a method to fill it automatically, it worked as intended.

Now when you click on an issue there's a panel on the right that shows the issue's data, but I just can't get it to work

The XML should be fine, I parsed it using this method.

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    list(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "issuesData.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

The list method there is this one, its the one that fills the column I mentioned

```
function list(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var list="";
  issues = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ISSUE");
  for (i = 0; i <issues.length; i++) { 
    list += "<li>" +
    issues[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLEENG")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</li>";
  }
  document.getElementById("issueList").innerHTML = list;
}
```

I have the variable issues as a global variable as I need to be able to acces it from multiple methods, essentially my idea is that onLoad the method loadDoc is ran and I have the var issues full of the data I need, at last that's how I want it to be.

I want to display the info about a certain issue when the application loads, so I wrote this method

```
function current(pos){
    document.getElementById("titleEng").innerHTML = issues[pos].getElementsByTagName("TITLEENG")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

But the application doesn't work, I get the error mentioned before, I thought the problem was using a method that takes arguments, or that the element id was wrong, and honestly after reading the code a dozen times and looking online I still have no clue what the problem is, I figure I must be due to the global value, as the full error message is:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'issues[0].getElementsByTagName') (00:42:51:853 | error, javascript)
```

I guess javascript doesn't know what issues is? Honestly the error is so non descriptive I have no clue what's wrong and what to do.

I very much tried looking for someone else with the same error

Comment: `famitsuIssues[pos]..getElementsByTagName` It should throw a `SyntaxError`. Also, you never defined `famitsuIssues`, what is it?

Comment: That isn't the issue, I just put it wrong here, its been edited, the variable is simply defined as var nothing else

var issues;

Comment: Sounds like `issues[pos]` is undefined - one of the calls of `current` is with an argument whose index does not exist in `issues`.

Comment: I tried doing something like issues[0] or getting issues.length and I get the same error.

Comment: Hrm, so maybe `issues` is not defined at the point that you call `current`. Can you post the context of where you call `current` in relation to where you call `loadDoc`?

Comment: There's a method called start that calls loadDoc(); and current(0), the method start is the one called onLoad in the HTML document. The idea is for it to show the very first issue when it starts, hence 0. LoadDoc always runs before current.

Comment: Hey, that other question was not able to help me, I still don't know how to get my code to work.

Comment: `loadDoc` is asynchronous, so you cannot have `current` run *synchronously* after you run `loadDoc`, else the asynchronous information (like your global variable) won't be defined at that point.

Comment: Then what can I do to fix it? I read the other question numerous times but I just don't get it.

Comment: See canonical here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call